# Getting values from a hidden field to another page

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to mvc so sorry if this sounds stupid :

I have a view, with the below code:

```
  using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "testcontroller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("customerReferenceNumber", "116999")
        @Html.Hidden("customerName", "John Smith")
        @Html.Hidden("mobileNumber", "12345")
        <input type="submit" value="Mobile Lost or Stolen?" />
    }
```

I another view called testview2 and a controller called testcontroller, with one method:

```
   public string Index(int customerref,string customername,string mobilenumber)
    {


    }
```

How do I get the hardcoded values from the html.hidden fields to the other page after the button click on the first view?

Comment: Well your form doesn't appear to be posting to the Index method on the TestController, so I'm not sure what you're trying to solve.

Comment: I've changed this but I still don't have a clue?

Comment: Why is the return type of Index `string` and not `ActionResult`?

Comment: I was just testing returning a query string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

actionPlease create second index action in this same controller and add [httppost] filter to it

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "testcontroller", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.Hidden("customerReferenceNumber", 116999)
        @Html.Hidden("customerName", "John Smith")
        @Html.Hidden("mobileNumber", "12345")
        <input type="submit" value="Mobile Lost or Stolen?" />
    }


[HttpPost]
public string Index(int customerReferenceNumber,string customerName,string mobileNumber)
    {


    }
```

Comment: Thank you, how do I assign customerref to the relevant hidden field in the view?

Comment: please remove quotations marks from customer customerReferenceNumber if you want pass it as int not a string

Comment: and is everything ok ?

Answer (score 0):

If you probably [name your parameters correctly it seems to work fine](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w5btZt), that is to say you need the input name to match the parameter in the method.

> "**customerReferenceNumber**" is not equal to "**customerref**"

Additionally, since you didn't pass `customerref` it should throw an exception because it requires an `int`, and MVC has no idea what `int` to pass.

View:

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.ResultViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- template from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started -->

<html lang="en">
    <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.Hidden("customerReferenceNumber", "116999")
        @Html.Hidden("customerName", "John Smith")
        @Html.Hidden("mobileNumber", "12345")
        <input type="submit" value="Mobile Lost or Stolen?" />
    }

    @if (Model != null)
    {
        <p>
        Results: <br />
            @Model.CustomerReferenceNumber<br />
            @Model.CustomerName<br />
            @Model.MobileNumber<br />
        </p>
    }

    </body>
</html>
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ResultViewModel model = null;

        return View(model);
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(int customerReferenceNumber, 
                              string customerName, 
                              string mobileNumber)
    {               
        var model = new ResultViewModel();

        model.CustomerName = customerName;
        model.CustomerReferenceNumber = customerReferenceNumber;
        model.MobileNumber = mobileNumber;

        return View(model);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get it on another page means another controller say Controller2 ,"index" method , you should post view to another controller action with hidden fields bound to model.

```
@model HelloWorldMvcApp.ResultViewModel
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>


<html lang="en">
    <body>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","TestController2"))
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CustomerReferenceNumber)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.MobileNumber) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CustomerName)
    }
    </body>
</html>
```

In TestController2

```
[HttpPost]
ActionResult Index(ResultViewModel model) 
{
   //you will get values in model 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you use model or update your controller as

```
public string Index(int customerReferenceNumber, string customerName, string mobileNumber)
{

}
```

remember the parameter name is same as the the name of your hidden field.

Answer (score 0):

The names should match. By that only the parameter binding takes place.
And, a controller action always returns `ActionResult` or anything that is derived from it. The method you have wrote is considered as just a normal method, not a controller action

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "testcontroller", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.Hidden("customerReferenceNumber", "116999")
    @Html.Hidden("customerName", "John Smith")
    @Html.Hidden("mobileNumber", "12345")
    <input type="submit" value="Mobile Lost or Stolen?" />
}
```

this is okk. but the controller action should be defined as

```
public ActionResult Index(string customerReferenceNumber,string customerName,string mobileNumber)
{


}
```

Notice the change of name as well as the datatype in the parameter list.